# Getting Warning for deprecation without using setCapabilities class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, warnings, deprecated

I am creating a Selenium testing framework. I have created my baseclass and am adding things now. It is at a basic stage but already when executing a test class I get Warnings that Im not following W3C syntax. I have tried to google the error and understand where I am not following it, but the articles i find only mention the deprecated setCapabilites. What am I doing wrong?

Console Log text:

```
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found exact CDP implementation for version 101
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "chrome" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "networkConnectionEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
May 29, 2022 2:21:12 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
```

My base class:

```
package resources;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class base {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public Properties prop;

    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
        
        
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\Projects\\EclipseWorkspace\\E2EPrj\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\data.properties");
        prop = new Properties();
        
        prop.load(fis);
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        
        if(browserName.equals("chrome"))
        {
            //execute in chromedriver
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Projects\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("firefox"))
        {
            //execute in geckodriver
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Projects\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("IE"))
        {
            //execute in IEdriver
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Projects\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
//      driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        return driver;
    }
    
//  public String getScreenShotPath(String testCaseName, WebDriver driver) throws IOException
//  {
//      TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot) driver;
//      File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
//      String destinationFile = ".\\reports\\"+testCaseName+".png";
//      FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(destinationFile));
//      return destinationFile;
//  }
    
}
```

Comment: Hallo. I have the same situation. But the funniest thing is, that last week everything works well. I changed nothing in code since last Wednesday and today I'm not able to execute my tests.

Comment: Well my code runs fine but these warnings annoy me and make me worry that int he future i might run into problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's look an issue for the newest Selenium version(4.2.0),
Because its **Logging warnings when non-W3C caps are being used** [(release notes)](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/f2e40dc9867c7312b616c81d230f603cf6664535/java/CHANGELOG#L22)

and reported as a bug on Selenium Github Repo [ISSUE 10711](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10711).

as diemol (SeleniumHQ core member) commented, a patch will be released soon.

In fact, issue is coming from (Chrome, Edge and Gecko) driver's side

> when a session is created, driver's is returning non-W3C WebDriver caps

For now no need to worry about this warnings, the new Selenium release will ignore this warnings for ChromeDriver, EdgeWebDriver and GeckoDriver as you can see [commit on Selenium repo](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/2c66554f2660e533521dc630341a80d55f98e975) until this issue is fixed from the WebDrivers side.

- Issue for Chrome Driver reported [HERE](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4129).
- Issue for Edge Web Driver reported [HERE](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/23).
- Issue for Gecko Driver reported [HERE](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/23).

Comment: I didn't use selenium 4.2 but 4.1.4. The problem was caused by Eclipse update which has an impact on maven, I think so. I solved the problem by deleting Appium-java dependency from pom.xml and adding library manually to project. Now everything works well, but this is not a good solution. I dot want to update libraries manually.

Comment: Can you share the the logs and pom.xml file for your project

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved at selenium v4.2.2
Please see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

## v4.2.2

- Supported CDP versions: 85, 100, 101, 102
- Throwing warnings for non-W3C before creating session (#10741)
- Update ExpectedCondition to extend java util Function (#10695)
- Fixing SafariTechPreview